# Reuse Form HTML Elements on conditional

Tags: php, html

So I have a conditional that will either return `page` or `popup` under the `$mode` variable. Depending on the choice selected, particular HTML markup will be displayed.

So inside both the HTML markups, we have the `form` markup - The markup for the form will be the same in both conditionals.

Is there a way for me to call one single `<form>` element but reuse it in two different positions without having to call the same HTML code twice?

**Code**:

```php
<?php
$mode = get_field('mode');
?>

<?php if ($mode == 'page'): ?>
    <div class="container my-4">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center pardot-form">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h3>Pardot Form</h3>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="modalElement" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?= $id ?>"></div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?= $id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pardot Form</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&#10005;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can put the form in a separate file and just include it where you need it. That's commonly know as a "view partial" (a part of a view that can be reused multiple times so you only need to change it in one place, if you need to update it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP function. Or you can put it in a variable, which could be either a regular variable, or a constant. Or you can use an included file.

Of these solutions, putting it in a constant probably will incur the least overhead, and including a file will probably be the least efficient. However, in practice, outputting text is so quick that it's not going to be an appreciable performance hit. So I would choose which method to use based not on performance, but on readability and long-term maintainability of your code.

The function-based solution would be best if you anticipate the need to pass some parameter to it at some point. I.e. the code would be more extensible.

The main advantage of using an include file is if you want to also use the form in some other script. You can also combine the function- and include-file solutions, putting a function in an included file. This is how I do the majority of output that gets reused in multiple files. However, I recommend avoiding splitting something off into a separate file unless you have a need to do so. If the form only shows up in this one script, keep it in that script until you have a need to display the exact same form in another script. The reason is that it keeps your project simple, but it is trivial (not at all time consuming or difficult) to split stuff off into a separate file later on, as needed.

Also, in general, I avoid writing PHP code using the syntax you used, and instead prefer to use the following syntax:

```
<?php
$mode = get_field('mode');
if ($mode == 'page')
{
    echo <<<EOF
<put><html><here>
EOF;
    // Back to PHP code
}
else
{
    // Something else
}
?>
```

This may just be a personal preference, but I've found that it is a bit easier to debug code if the entire script is a PHP block and I avoid conditional blocks that close and reopen the `<? ... ?>` tag. If your script ends up growing and getting more complex, and you find yourself needing to add more conditions or functions or other PHP syntax within the conditional blocks, it will become unsustainable and need to be rewritten. The reason is that you cannot mix syntaxes within the same block, see explanation here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

and as a result, you cannot add PHP code that requires the other syntax, into your existing blocks. This makes your code less extensible in the long-run. On the other hand, encapsulating output HTML in the `echo <<<EOF ... EOF;` blocks can fit just fine within regular `if...then` blocks.

Comment: _"I've found that it is a bit easier to debug code if the entire script is a PHP block and I avoid conditional blocks that close and reopen the <? ... ?> tag"_ - I couldn't disagree more here. Outputting HTML though PHP should be avoided. If anything, this will make it _harder_ to debug since most IDE's won't syntax highlight HTML in PHP strings/blocks. Separating your back end and front end will make your code way less messy. If there's a HTML block that should be reused, put it in it's own file instead. Just organize your files and it won't be "complex". The performance hit is negligible

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You're right about the lack of syntax highlighting in this context. However, in my 16+ years of PHP coding I rarely have trouble locating and fixing HTML bugs within a known PHP file, whereas I spend a significant amount of time trying to figure out which file I need to edit to fix a particular bug. I also have worked with many other people's code where they include a file with a function used exactly once in the whole project. Different people may have different needs, which is why I wrote my answer conditionally and about my preference, not universal best practice.

Comment: If you just structure your code consistently (and follow well known patterns that makes sense for the context of your app), there shouldn't be any issues locating the correct partials. Tbh, in my 16+ years as a PHP dev, I've found that the the best way is to use some templating/view engine like twig, blade, plates or similar. Using those will make it _way_ easier to structure your views/partials than abstracting them away inside a bunch of custom PHP functions. And then only have view logic (if this, then show that) inside them, but keeping the business logic outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by declaring a php function to load a DOM object dynamically.

First create a dom object, then store your form content in a variable, and call that variable in you html string.
more information on [https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/getelementbyid-getelementsbytagname#:~:text=To%20traverse%20the%20elements%20of%20a%20PHP%20object%2C,of%20a%20HTML%20element%20with%20a%20specified%20ID](https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/getelementbyid-getelementsbytagname#:%7E:text=To%20traverse%20the%20elements%20of%20a%20PHP%20object%2C,of%20a%20HTML%20element%20with%20a%20specified%20ID).

```
          <?php

          function loadHTML() {

          $htmlDOM = new DOMDocument(); //create new DOM object
          $form = '<form>your form</form>';
          $htmlDOMstring = '<html><body>Tags and content' +$form +'the 
         rest.<br></body></html>';
           $htmlDOM->loadHTML($htmlDOMstring);


           }
           loadHTML();
           ?>
```

Comment: What happens if the `htmlDOMstring` has different markup? One has a container and the other is a modal.

Comment: I suppose you could wrap everything what you have so far in another function that handles the logic on when to call for 1 or the other, then define 2 seperate htmlDOMstrings, and call the one you want as needed. I think there are better ways to accomplish the same with less code, but it should work.